# How to create a virtual table in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found it easier to explain with musicians than with my actual data. 
Every Musician has an ID, used for their name and instruments.

`Select ID, NAME, PARAM FROM TABLE`

**CURRENT RESULT**

```
ID  NAME        PARAM
911 John        Name  
911 Guitar      Instr 1  
911 Piano       Instr 2
912 Paul        Name 
912 Bass        Instr 1
912 Piano       Instr 2
912 Guitar      Instr 3
913 Freddie     Name
913 Piano      Instr 1
913 Guitar     Instr 2
914 Brian      Name
914 Guitar     Instr 1
```

I would like to add a column 'Band' that I would need to create starting from the ID's

- BAND = B includes ('911', '912')
- BAND = Q includes ('913', '914')

**WANTED RESULT**

```
ID    NAME      PARAM    BAND
911 John        Name     B
911 Guitar      Instr 1  B
911 Piano       Instr 2  B 
912 Paul        Name     B
912 Bass        Instr 1  B
912 Piano       Instr 2  B
912 Guitar      Instr 3  B
913 Freddie     Name     Q
913 Piano      Instr 1  Q
913 Guitar     Instr 2  Q
914 Brian      Name     Q
914 Guitar     Instr 1  Q
```

Comment: So, what is your question here? You've stated your goals, which is good, but what do you need help with? What have you tried? Welcome to StackOverflow, however, it's not a free coding service, it's Q&A website.

Comment: What is a virtual table?

Comment: Why not just create a `Table`?

Comment: There are tables in SQL (the language), there are views, but there are *NO* "virtual tables".

Comment: For future reference, have a look at this link, especially the part about DDL:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Dumbo if you google for `sql virtual table` you'll find in the very first page people talking about views, temporary tables and table variables. SQLite has a `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` clause that refers to temprary tables.

Comment: This does not seem like a good thing to do.  You have an entity-attribute-value (EAV) model.  Adding addition "features" as columns is contrary to the spirit of such a model.

Answer (score 4):

The query will give you desired result:

```
select id,
       name,
       param,
       case when id in (911,912) then 'B' when id in (913,914) then 'Q' end [Band]
from MY_TABLE
```

Now, if you want you can `CREATE VIEW`

```
create view v_tableWithBand as
select id,
       name,
       param,
       case when id in (911,912) then 'B' when id in (913,914) then 'Q' end [Band]
from MY_TABLE
```

store result in temporary table:

```
select id,
       name,
       param,
       case when id in (911,912) then 'B' when id in (913,914) then 'Q' end [Band]
into #tempTableWithBand 
from MY_TABLE
```

or in table variable:

```
declare @tableWithBand table (id int, name varchar(100), param varchar(100), band char(1))
insert into @tableWithBand 
select id,
       name,
       param,
       case when id in (911,912) then 'B' when id in (913,914) then 'Q' end [Band]
from MY_TABLE
```

and query this data.

Comment: Very comprehensive :-D

Comment: I was confused by `virtual table`, so I had to guess :)

Answer (score 3):

Your data is not [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

I know it looks like a pain to break up the table but it works.  For example if the band name changes you do it in one spot.  A musician can be in more than one band.

```
Musician 
ID int PK 
Name varchar(200)

Instrument
ID int PK 
Name varchar(200) 

MusicianInstrument
musician in FK  
insturment int FK 
composite PK

Band 
ID int PK 
Name varchar(200) 

MusicianBand
musician int FK  
band int FK

select m.Name, i.Name, b.Name
 from Musician m 
 left join MusicianInsturment mi 
   on mi.Musician = m.ID 
 left join Insturment i 
   on i.ID = mi.Insturment 
 left join MusicianBand mb 
   on mb.Musician = m.ID 
 left join Band b
   on b.ID = mb.Band
```

Comment: Great! Very important hints

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expression :

```
select *,
        (case when ID in (911, 912) 
              then 'B' 
              when ID in (913, 914)
              then 'Q' 
         end) as BAND
from table t;
```